# Convert string in javascript to devexpress control

Tags: devexpress

I am saving a list of dynamically created ASPxRadioButtonList(s) in a hidden input that gets filled in a callbackpanel, SO that when a user checks a checkbox to ENABLE all, I can loop through all these RBL's and enable them on the client side.

However, I cannot figure out how to convert my string name of the control "audit-Something" to the actual control so that I can check the Enabled list item... here's an image of what I have:

[image]

I keep getting the error:  Object doesn't support property or method 'SetValue'

Thoughts?

Comment: Did yout set radio button [ClientInstanceName](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxEditorsEditPropertiesBase_ClientInstanceNametopic) on server side?

Comment: I set the radiobuttonlist ClientInstanceName ..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly, but I will try to help. If not please post relevant part of server side code.

If you have ASPxRadioButtonList names in hidden field than do this:

1. Set ASPxRadioButtonList ClientInstanceName on server side. Every ASPxRadioButtonList should have different ClientInstanceName value. Save those clientinstancenames in you hidden.
2. Then:

```
for(var i = 0; i < auditControls.length; i++) {
    var clientInstanceName = auditControls[i];
    window[clientInstanceName].SetEnabled(true);
}
```

This will enable all radiobuttonlist controls.

Comment: THAT's it!!!  Awesome!  I would have NEVER guessed that!  (I really am not a fan of devex tools, wish I could just use basic Javascript -- but thank YOU for knowing how to use them!)

Comment: TO BE CLEAR - you don't need the var clientInstanceName line... the only thing that was missing was the window[ ] .